# The state has changed but the render don't called again

Tags: reactjs, redux

reducer

```
`
saveEnd(state, action){
  let data = action.payload;
  let data1 = {};
  data1['' + data.platform] = {};
  data1['' + data.platform]['' + data.type] = data;
  $.extend(true, state.serCfgData, data1);
  return state
}
`
```

I find the state has changed in the chrome redux develop tools, but the view don't update, then when I use `return {...state}` the view is update, I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

When you see your redux store update but do not see the component rerender, one of the first things you should do is check to see if your state object is being mutated.

According to the jquery documentation on extend:

> Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the **first
>   object**.

Note that in your code:

```
// jQuery.extend( [deep ], target, object1 [, objectN ] )
$.extend(true, state.serCfgData, data1);
```

You are mutating the state object rather than a copy of it.
You can do something like this to avoid mutating the state:

```
...
...
// Babel Stage 3 spread operator
const newState = {...state};

$.extend(true, newState.serCfgData, data1);
return newState;
```

Note that when you `return {...state}`, the reason it updates is you are returning a new object (Spread operator creates a new object.)

Take a look at this video to understand how to avoid object mutations in your reducer:

https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-object-mutations-with-object-assign-and-spread

Comment: Yep, this is correct.  Also see info in the Redux docs on accidental mutations and properly updating data immutably: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-not-rerendering and http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html .  Also, a couple notes: the object spread operator is Stage 3, not ES6, but ES6 does have `Object.assign()`. Either way, those are commonly used, rather than `$.extend`.

Comment: Ah thats correct, I'll update my answer to reflect Stage 3 rather than ES6.

Comment: thanks, I had used `Object.assign()`， but this method don't work in a deep object

Comment: Yeah, `Object.assign` is a shallow merge.  The "Immutable Update Patterns" link gives an example of doing a nested update using shallow merges, as well as other possible approaches.  I'm really not sure if `$.extend()` actually does proper immutable updates or not if you pass `true` for the "deep" flag.